# Is there a simple way to trigger form validation onSubmit instead of onLoad with bootstrap and Vue.Js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, bootstrap-vue

I have a Password reset form which is initially empty of course, and I want to validate at submit that none of the fields is empty. I'm doing the following for each field:

```
    <b-form-group id="currentPassword" 
              label="Old password"
              :invalid-feedback="oldPasswordFeedback">
        <b-form-input id="password" 
                      v-model="passwords.currentPassword" 
                      placeholder="Enter your old Password" 
                      type="password"  
                      maxlength="60" 
                      required/>
    </b-form-group>
```

and the form is defined like this

```
  <b-form validated="" id="passwordChangeForm" @submit.prevent="changePassword" class="container-fluid">
```

The problem is that whenever I navigate to the page, all fields are marked invalid by default and displaying their error messages since they are empty. I want the validation to take place when I submit the form. Is there a simple way to do that without having to install extra validation plugins?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your component declaration you have set `required` attribute which try to validate your form when you come to load your page, so you could take advantage of `Vue.js` and create `req` property in your data object which is initially set to `false`.

I'm providing the following simplified example to show you how to do that

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',

  data() {
    return {
    item:'',
     currentPassword:'',
     req:false
    }
  },
  methods: {
  changePassword: function() {
    this.req=true;
    }
  }

});
```

```html
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//unpkg.com/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@latest/dist/bootstrap-vue.css" />

<!-- Add this after vue.js -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.js"></script>
<script src="//unpkg.com/babel-polyfill@latest/dist/polyfill.min.js"></script>
<script src="//unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@latest/dist/bootstrap-vue.js"></script>


<div id="app" class="container">
  <div>
    
    <b-form validated="" id="passwordChangeForm" @submit.prevent="changePassword" class="container-fluid">
      <b-form-group id="currentPassword" label="Old password">
        <b-form-input id="password" v-model="currentPassword" placeholder="Enter your old Password" type="password" :required="req" />
      </b-form-group>
      <b-button type="submit" variant="primary">Submit</b-button>
    </b-form>
  </div>
</div>
```